# CSS: center a fixed div

Tags: css, position, alignment

I have a class for a fixed positioned div to stay at the bottom of the view port. I am trying to make the width automatic so that as the div changes width, it remains centered.

```
.box {
position: fixed;
width: 80%;
bottom: 20px;
left: 50%;
margin: 0 0 0 -40%;
max-height: 50%;
overflow: auto
}
```

Any ideas? I tried a container with text-align: center then display: inline, but it produced crazy results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.box {
    position   : fixed;
    left       : 10%;
    right      : 10%;
    bottom     : 20px;
    max-height : 50%;
    overflow   : auto;
}
```

You can use `left` and `right` together to center the element (instead of using width).

If you want to use width then you can do this:

```
.box {
    position   : fixed;
    left       : 10%;
    width      : 80%;
    bottom     : 20px;
    max-height : 50%;
    overflow   : auto;
}
```

If you want to center HTML inside the fixed element you can do this:

```
.box > div {
    width      : 50%;
    min-width  : 150px;
    margin     : 0 auto;
    text-align : center;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dFXt5/

Comment: That still keeps the width at 80%? I would like the width to be dynamic based on the data it contains - for example if it contains just one word, that word should be in the center of a tiny div, not a div that takes up 80% of the view port.

Comment: Check-out the demo. The nested div does just that. If you remove the border and background colors the text floats in the middle of the viewport.

Comment: Oh thanks. I was on IE6 and forget the > in the CSS doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
.centered {  position: fixed;  top: 50%;  left: 50%;  margin-top: -[1/2(element-height)];  margin-left: -[1/2(element-width)];}
```

This work.